# Angular JS - How to catch Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed exception

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need to verify that object that i;m adding into array of the objects is not existing in temporary array of objects.

Angula JS throwing error Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. But this error is not catched using try/ catch.

Is possible to check for this kind of exception or check that object is already exist in the array of the objects?

Thanks for any help.

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
  $scope.availableSounds = [
            {
                name: "Rain"
            },
            {
                name: "Storm"
            },
            {
                name: "Forest"
            },
        ];        

$scope.selectedSounds = [];
```

ADDING OF ITEMS (OBJECT IN THE ARRAY OF THE SELECTED SOUND SHOULD BE UNIQUE)

```
$scope.addSoundToSelection = function(index) {
            try {
                var selectedItem = $scope.availableSounds[index];
                $scope.selectedSounds.push(selectedItem);
                var pos = $scope.selectedSounds.map(function(e) { return e.hello; }).indexOf(selectedItem.name);
                console.log(pos);
            } catch(e) {
                $scope.showAlert();
            }
        };
```

Comment: Instead of catching, why don't you avoid the error. If you use track by (with some identifier or worst case even the index ) or avoid repeating primitives you should be able to eliminate the possibility of the error. However please share the piece of code that is troubling you.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: `ng-repeat= "thing in things track by $index"` should solve the error

Comment: Although this is not clear from the documentation, AngularJS needs to be able to clearly differentiate between items in the array it's `ng-repeat`ing over. By doing this it can optimize DOM manipulation. Using `track by` ensures that it can.

Comment: With the limited code displayed (You are not showing us the complete context) assume you are getting the error when repeating `selectedSounds` because you are pushing the same item (with the same $$hashKey) again. Using  `$scope.selectedSounds.push(angular.clone(selectedItem));` should also eliminate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about indexOf method

```
var myObjectToAdd = {};
var myArray = [ {}, {} ] //some array of objects

if (myArray.indexOf(myObjectToAdd) < 0) {
 myArray.add(myObjectToAdd);
}
```

Alternately you can use _.find of the lodash library

Comment: I've never heard of the `array.add()` function. Did you mean `array.push()`? I get `TypeError: arr.add is not a function`. Can't find anything in Angular referencing `add()` either. However, the method you outlined here worked for our problem :)